# How to call upon puppet token that has just been generated to use to unpin nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, puppet

```html
curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"login": "user", "password": "pass"}' https://server:4433/rbac-api/v1/auth/token
```

The command above i use to generate the token i need the next command uses it to run the following

```html
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "X-Authentication:$token" -d '{"nodes": ["foo.tld", "bar.tld", "baz.tld"]}' https://$HOSTNAME:4433/classifier-api/v1/commands/unpin-from-all
```

The problem I'm having is I have been manually inserting the token to unpin my nodes. I want to be able to call upon the token once its been generated in Linux so I don't have to copy and paste it every time. What command would i need to add to script to do this, if possible the same for the nodes.

Comment: You can do this in just about any language that supports json parsing and http requests (which is most of them: python with urllib, ruby with http, perl, js, etc. are easy interpretive languages). Write a line of code to make the request in the first line, write a second line to grab the token from the json output, and then write a third line to use the token in a second request.

Comment: @MattSchuchard What would the request look like in shell that is my issue. Not sure how to grab the token from the json output.

Comment: Write a script with those three lines of code and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

whether you are going to use a shell script or manual commands, you should be using labels for your tokens.

from [puppet api docs](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/rbac/rbac_token_auth_intro.html#configuration-file-settings-for-puppet-access):

> {"login": "YOUR PE USER NAME", "password": "YOUR PE PASSWORD", "label": "Ava's token"}

this makes the token easier to call

hope that helps

Comment: I tried what you suggested and added a label to the token to call upon but when i added label to the section that generates my label when i try calling upon it in the second script nothing happens says token has been revoked but when i copy and paste it works fine. 'curl -k -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"login": "user", "password": "pass", "label": "nodetoken"}' https://server:4433/rbac-api/v1/auth/token'

Comment: curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "X-Authentication:nodetoken" -d '{"nodes": ["foo.tld", "bar.tld", "baz.tld"]}' https://$HOSTNAME:4433/classifier-api/v1/commands/unpin-from-all

Comment: Although this is reasonable advice, it is not responsive to the actual question.  It would be more appropriate for a comment than an answer.